# Bitbucket Pipelines: Setting up two databases from a postgres image

Tags: postgresql, docker, bitbucket-pipelines

I am trying to initialize two databases in PostgreSQL from the docker image from Dockerhub in my bitbucket pipeline. I found a tutorial online and I followed their instructions: https://dev.to/bgord/multiple-postgres-databases-in-a-single-docker-container-417l However, despite mounting the .sh script over to the correct place, the initialization script still does not run. Instead, in the logs of my bitbucket pipeline, I get `/usr/local/bin/docker-entrypoint.sh: ignoring /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/*` and the databases are never created.

```
definitions:
  services:
    docker:
      # increase docker service memory, otherwise sonar scanner will fail
      # 3072 is the max for a pipelines job, anything above 3072 will use 2x the build minutes
      memory: 3072
    postgres:
      image: postgres
      environment:
        POSTGRES_MULTIPLE_DATABASES: emailservice,meta_db
        POSTGRES_USER: auth
        POSTGRES_PASSWORD: auth
      volumes:
        - ./db_init/db_init.sh:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/db_init.sh
      ports:
        - 5432:5432
```

And here is how my step is defined:

```
  steps:
    - step: &run-tests
        runs-on:
          - "ctix"
          - "self.hosted"
        name: Unit Tests
        image: python:3.8.1
        size: 2x
        caches:
          - docker
          - pip
          - sonar
        services:
          - docker
          - postgres
        script:
          - pip install -r requirements.txt -q
          - mkdir -p test-reports/
          - pytest --cov-report xml:coverage.xml --cov=./
        artifacts:
          - test-reports/**
```

Comment: I fear you are confusing docker-compose.yml with bitbucket-pipelines.yml. I find no documentation about that `volumes` section (nor `ports`) in your service definition. Both are YAML but the applications consuming that YAML are totally different. See https://support.atlassian.com/bitbucket-cloud/docs/databases-and-service-containers/

Comment: You are right, I assumed that the same fields that exist in Docker exist in Bitbucket Pipelines, but I guess that's not true.

Answer (score 1):

Since a `volume` section doesn't exist, I instead generated the databases using a script

```
scripts:
    - pip install -r requirements.txt -q
    - apt-get update && apt-get -y install postgresql-client
    - ./docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/db_init.sh
```

With `db_init.sh` containing:

```
#!/bin/bash

export POSTGRES_MULTIPLE_DATABASES=emailservice,meta_db
export POSTGRES_USER=auth
export POSTGRES_PASSWORD=auth

set -e
set -u

function create_user_and_database() {
    local database=$1
    echo "  Creating user and database '$database'"
    psql -v ON_ERROR_STOP=1 -h localhost --username "$POSTGRES_USER" postgres <<-EOSQL
        CREATE USER $database;
        CREATE DATABASE $database;
        GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON DATABASE $database TO $database;
EOSQL
}

if [ -n "$POSTGRES_MULTIPLE_DATABASES" ]; then
    echo "Multiple database creation requested: $POSTGRES_MULTIPLE_DATABASES"
    for db in $(echo $POSTGRES_MULTIPLE_DATABASES | tr ',' ' '); do
        create_user_and_database $db
    done
    echo "Multiple databases created"
fi
```